# List objects adding same data multiple times in asmx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asmx

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to fetch lists for UnionCouncil and BEMISCode(Schoolid) from EMIS_DB(DataBase1) and PBHId(BudgetId) list from DSS_DB(DataBase2) and show sum of AlocatedBudget for each UnionCouncil if it has any.
So far i am getting the values of listobjects.counts() but the sum of AlocatedBudget is showing correctly only for first UnionCouncil and then it adds the sum of AlocatedBudget into others.

**for example:** AllocatedBudget for UnionCuncil abc is 208000  AllocatedBudget for UnionCouncil xyz will be double of previous AllocatedBudget  like 416000.

I have tried almost everything but couldn't find what is missing, any kind of help is much much appreciated.

**Client side**

```
<div class="panel-body">

                <div id="tblschoolinfo" style="background-color: #F8F8F8; color: rgb(1, 51, 1);">
```

**Function**

```
function LoadBudgetSumCouncilvise()
        {
            var table = $("#tblschoolinfo");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wbservices/GetBudgetEstimatedSumByUnionCouncil.asmx/getunioncouncil",
                //data: jsnDta,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {

                    var rtnData = r.d; //all returned data...
                    var respDta = [];
                    $.map(rtnData, function (item, index) {
                        var j = [
                            item.status,
                            item.msg,
                        ];
                        respDta.push(j);

                    });
                    $.each(respDta, function (key, value) {
                        var status = value[0];
                        var msg = value[1];

                        alert(msg);
                        if (status == true) {

                            table.html(msg);

                        } else {

                            var eMsg = '<div style="color:white;background:#FF4040" ><i style="margin-left:5px" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>"' + msg + '"</div>';
                            table.html(eMsg);

                        }

                    }); //1st out loop ends here...


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //  $("#responseMovDetails").html(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
                    alert("error while loading Records of Requests" + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

            });
        }
```

**ASMX**

```
        public List<RequestResponse> getunioncouncil()
    {


        List<RequestResponse> list = new List<RequestResponse>();
        RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();

        string District = Session["districtName"].ToString();

        Pro_DbCon obj2 = new Pro_DbCon();

        //EMIS conncection
        SqlConnection conemis = obj2.dbconnectionEMIS();
        string rows = "";


        List<string> uc = new List<string>();
        List<string> bemiscode = new List<string>();
        List<string>pbhid=new List<string>();
        List<string> pbdid = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            conemis.Open();
            //get unoincouncil
            string getuc = "select distinct(UnionCouncil) from Locations where District = @dis";
            SqlCommand cmduc = new SqlCommand(getuc,conemis);
            cmduc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis",District);
            SqlDataReader ucdr = cmduc.ExecuteReader();

            while(ucdr.Read())
            {
                uc.Add(ucdr[0].ToString());
            }

            ucdr.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < uc.Count();i++ )
            {
                //get bemiscode by unioncouncil
            string getbemiscode = "select VchBEMISCode from SchoolsParameter where VchUC = @uc";
            SqlCommand getcode = new SqlCommand(getbemiscode,conemis);
            getcode.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uc",uc[i]);
            SqlDataReader bemiscodedr = getcode.ExecuteReader();

                while(bemiscodedr.Read())
                {
                    bemiscode.Add(bemiscodedr[0].ToString());
                }

                bemiscodedr.Close();

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            r.status = false;
            r.msg = "Could not get data from EmisDb!" + ex.ToString();
            list.Add(r);
        }
        finally
        {
            conemis.Close();
        }


        //Dss connection
        string constr = obj2.dbconnection();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        try
        {                
            con.Open();
            for (int a = 0; a < uc.Count(); a++)
            { 

                //----------------------------------
                Decimal EstimatedAmountTaat = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountScience = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountReadWriting = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountFurniture = 0;

                Decimal UtilizedAmountTaat = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountScience = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountReadingWriting = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountFurniture = 0;
                //----------------------------------

                for (int i = 0; i < bemiscode.Count(); i++)
                {
                    //check bemiscode exists in budgetview

                    //get budgethead by bemiscode
                    string getbudgethead = "select * from Pro_BudgetView where BEMSCode = @scode";
                    SqlCommand bheadcmd = new SqlCommand(getbudgethead, con);
                    bheadcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scode", bemiscode[i]);
                    SqlDataReader dr = bheadcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (dr[1].ToString() == bemiscode[i].ToString())
                        {
                            pbhid.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                    dr.Close();

                }
                //-------------------------------------------
                for (int j = 0; j < pbhid.Count(); j++)
                {

                    //get budgetdetail by budgethead
                    string getbudgetdetail = "select * from Pro_BudgetView where PBHId = @pbhid";
                    SqlCommand getbudgetdetailcmd = new SqlCommand(getbudgetdetail, con);
                    getbudgetdetailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbhid", pbhid[j]);
                    SqlDataReader bdreader = getbudgetdetailcmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (bdreader.Read())
                    {
                        pbdid.Add(bdreader[5].ToString());

                        if(bdreader[6].ToString()=="1")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountTaat = EstimatedAmountTaat + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[7].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountTaat = UtilizedAmountTaat + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[8].ToString());
                        }

                        if (bdreader[6].ToString() == "2")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountScience = EstimatedAmountScience + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[7].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountScience = UtilizedAmountScience + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[8].ToString());
                        }

                        if (bdreader[6].ToString() == "3")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountReadWriting = EstimatedAmountReadWriting + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[7].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountReadingWriting = UtilizedAmountReadingWriting + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[8].ToString());
                        }

                        if (bdreader[6].ToString() == "4") 
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountFurniture = EstimatedAmountFurniture + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[7].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountFurniture = UtilizedAmountFurniture + Convert.ToDecimal(bdreader[8].ToString());
                        }

                    }

                    bdreader.Close();

                }

                string row = "<tr><td colspan='4' style='text-align:center;'>" + uc[a].ToString() + "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>AlocatedBudget(sum)</b></td><td>" + EstimatedAmountTaat + "</td><td>" + EstimatedAmountScience + "</td><td>" + EstimatedAmountReadWriting + "</td><td>" + EstimatedAmountFurniture + "</td></tr>  <tr><td><b>UtiliazedAmount(sum)</b></td><td>" + UtilizedAmountTaat + "</td><td>" + UtilizedAmountScience + "</td><td>" + UtilizedAmountReadingWriting + "</td><td>" + UtilizedAmountFurniture + "</td></tr>";
                rows = rows + row;

            }
            con.Close();
            if(rows!="")
            {
                r.status = true;
                r.msg = rows + "";
                list.Add(r);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            r.status = false;
            r.msg = "Error" + ex.ToString();
            list.Add(r);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: You should focus your question, is the problem in the Javascript or in the server side, put a debugger and break point in the asmx and see where is the problem...

Comment: Your are right the problem is in my asmx code after getting sum against valid listobject values listobject pbhid readds same ids in itself   them again. How do i prevent it ?

Comment: It's really difficult to see what's wrong with your code, you should divide it into smaller functions and debug it and see what's wrong.

Comment: Almost Done :)...
I have to rewrite almost  my all code.

Comment: When you write your code in small function it's much easier to maintain that code and fix specific problems.

Comment: BTW , you use int i twice, maybe it's affecting your code.

Comment: yes it defiantly were affecting that int i was the main reason of itration

Comment: Kindly check my answer and vote if u think its fine now. Though its working fine now.

Comment: If it works as expected then I am happy for you, if any if my comments helped in some how you can up vote them, good luck.

Comment: vote my answer if it looks ok to u it will help others too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its logical problem but this kind of mistake we often make and it can save much much time for others.

### Changes

1. Declare List Where its needed (Scope).
2. looping through Listobjects and only nest where query is dependent on 1 to many.

Here is what I did.

```
    public class GetBudgetEstimatedSumByUnionCouncil : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]
    public List<RequestResponse> getunioncouncil()
    {


        List<RequestResponse> list = new List<RequestResponse>();
        RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();

        string District = Session["districtName"].ToString();

        Pro_DbCon obj2 = new Pro_DbCon();

        //EMIS conncection
        SqlConnection conemis = obj2.dbconnectionEMIS();
        string rows = "";

        //Dss connection
        string constr = obj2.dbconnection();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        List<string> uc = new List<string>();

        //List<string>pbhid=new List<string>();

        try
        {
            conemis.Open();
            //get unoincouncil
            string getuc = "select distinct(UnionCouncil) from Locations where District = @dis";
            SqlCommand cmduc = new SqlCommand(getuc,conemis);
            cmduc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis",District);
            SqlDataReader ucdr = cmduc.ExecuteReader();

            while(ucdr.Read())
            {
                uc.Add(ucdr[0].ToString());
            }

            ucdr.Close();
            conemis.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < uc.Count();i++ )
            {
                //----------------------------------
                Decimal EstimatedAmountTaat = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountScience = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountReadWriting = 0;
                Decimal EstimatedAmountFurniture = 0;

                Decimal UtilizedAmountTaat = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountScience = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountReadingWriting = 0;
                Decimal UtilizedAmountFurniture = 0;
                //----------------------------------

                List<string> bemiscode = new List<string>();
                List<string> pbdid = new List<string>();
                //get bemiscode by unioncouncil
                conemis.Open();
            string getbemiscode = "select VchBEMISCode from SchoolsParameter where VchUC = @uc";
            SqlCommand getcode = new SqlCommand(getbemiscode,conemis);
            getcode.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uc",uc[i]);
            SqlDataReader bemiscodedr = getcode.ExecuteReader();

                while(bemiscodedr.Read())
                {
                    bemiscode.Add(bemiscodedr[0].ToString());
                }

                bemiscodedr.Close();
                conemis.Close();
                //----------------------------------
                con.Open();
                for (int b = 0; b < bemiscode.Count(); b++)
                {

                    //get budgethead by bemiscode
                    string getbudgethead = "select * from Pro_BudgetView where BEMSCode = @scode";
                    SqlCommand bheadcmd = new SqlCommand(getbudgethead, con);
                    bheadcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scode", bemiscode[b]);
                    SqlDataReader dr = bheadcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                            pbdid.Add(dr[5].ToString());                           

                    }

                    dr.Close();

                }

                //----------------------------
                for (int j = 0; j < pbdid.Count(); j++)
                {                        
                    //get budgetdetail by budgethead
                    string getbudgetdetail = "select PBHId,EstimatedAmount,UtilizedAmount,CId,PBDId from Pro_BudgetView where PBDId = @pbdid and BudgetStatus = @bs";
                    SqlCommand getbudgetdetailcmd = new SqlCommand(getbudgetdetail, con);
                    getbudgetdetailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbdid", pbdid[j]);
                    getbudgetdetailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bs", "2");
                    SqlDataReader bdr = getbudgetdetailcmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (bdr.Read())
                    {
                        //pbdid.Add(bdr[4].ToString());
                        if (bdr[3].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountTaat = EstimatedAmountTaat + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[1].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountTaat = UtilizedAmountTaat + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[2].ToString());
                        }
                        if (bdr[3].ToString() == "2")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountScience = EstimatedAmountScience + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[1].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountScience = UtilizedAmountScience + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[2].ToString());
                        }
                        if (bdr[3].ToString() == "3")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountReadWriting = EstimatedAmountReadWriting + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[1].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountReadingWriting = UtilizedAmountReadingWriting + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[2].ToString());
                        }
                        if (bdr[3].ToString() == "4")
                        {
                            EstimatedAmountFurniture = EstimatedAmountFurniture + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[1].ToString());
                            UtilizedAmountFurniture = UtilizedAmountFurniture + Convert.ToDecimal(bdr[2].ToString());
                        }

                    }

                    bdr.Close();
                }
                string row = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;font-size: large;'><b>UnionCouncil</b></td><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center;font-size: x-large;'>" + uc[i].ToString() + "</td></tr> <tr><td style='text-align:center;font-size: large;'><b>AlocatedBudget(sum)</b></td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + EstimatedAmountTaat + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + EstimatedAmountScience + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + EstimatedAmountReadWriting + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + EstimatedAmountFurniture + "</td></tr>  <tr><td style='text-align:center;font-size: large;'><b>UtiliazedAmount(sum)</b></td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + UtilizedAmountTaat + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + UtilizedAmountScience + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + UtilizedAmountReadingWriting + "</td><td style='text-align:center;'>" + UtilizedAmountFurniture + "</td></tr>";
                    rows = rows + row;
                con.Close();
                if(rows!="")
                {
                    r.status = true;
                    r.msg = rows + "";
                    list.Add(r);
                }
            }              
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            r.status = false;
            r.msg = "Could not get data from EmisDb!" + ex.ToString();
            list.Add(r);
        }
        finally
        {
            conemis.Close();
            con.Close();
        }

        return list;
    }
```